# Equivalent to consumer group in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, apache-kafka, cassandra-3.0

I'm trying to create a sort of a [consumer group](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#intro_consumers) as it exist in `Kafka` but for `Cassandra`. The goal is to have a request been paginated and each page done by one instance of an App. 
Is there any notion like the [consumer group](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#intro_consumers) one in `Cassandra` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TL;DR; is that no, the consumer-group notion doesn't exist in the clients in Cassandra. The burden of which client processes what is entirely on the app developer.

You can use Cassandra's [tokens](https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html#reference_ds_d35_v2q_xj__paging-through-unordered-results) to do selective paging.

Assuming 2 clients (easy example)
Client 1 pages from -2^63 to 0
Client 2 pages from 1 to 2^63 - 1

The above idea assumes you want to page through all the data in something similar to a batch process which wouldn't be a good fit for Cassandra.

If you're after the latest N results, where the 1st half is sent to client 1 and the second to client 2 you can use a logical bucket in your partitioning key.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to scale the processing of a large number of Cassandra rows, you might consider a scalable execution platform like Flink or Storm. You'd be able to parallelize both the reading of the rows and the processing of the rows, although a parallelizable source (or spout in Storm) is not something you can get out of the box.

Comment: Unfortunatly, I'm not able to change the execution platform ... Otherwise I would have used either Flink, Spark, Storm or Akka (streams)